# mongo-cxx driver cannot find polyfill for unique_ptr

Tags: c++, mongodb, cmake, mongo-cxx-driver, mongo-c-driver

I'm trying to build `mongo-cxx-driver` on Windows; I'm following the [instructions](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/), but am getting errors:

```
C1189   #error:  "Cannot find a valid polyfill for make_unique"
```

Here's what I did:

### Building mongo-c-driver

I cloned `mongo-c-driver` using the specified minimum release (1.15):

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-c-driver --branch r1.15
```

Using CMake-Gui (I'm using 3.18.2), I generated the .proj file using Visual Studio 16 2019 Generator.  I used the default settings:

[image: Cmake-Gui build settings for mongo-c-driver]

This builds successfully, and I can find the corresponding .dll and .lib files in `C:\Program Files (x86)\mongo-c-driver`.

### Building mongo-cxx-driver

I cloned the project using my desired version (compatible with the above version of `mongo-c-driver`):

```
git clone https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-cxx-driver --branch releases/v3.5
```

I used Cmake-Gui to configure the CMake parameters, configuring the paths to where I installed `mongo-c`:

[image]

Of note:

- I did not fill out `bson-1.0_DIR` or `mongoc-1.0_DIR` because I can't figure out what they're looking for.
- I set `BSONCXX_POLY_USE_STD=1` because I am using C++17 and do not want to use `std::experimental` or Boost.

I tried to compile this in Visual Studio, and got the above error about not finding a valid polyfill for `make_unique`.  Where did I go wrong?

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer seems to be in the [installation guide](http://mongocxx.org/mongocxx-v3/installation/), I missed a step:

> For building with Visual Studio 2017 (without a C++17 polyfill), it is
> necessary to configure with an additional option, /Zc:__cplusplus to
> opt into the correct definition of __cplusplus (problem described
> here):
>
> 'C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe' .. 
> -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64"            
> -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17                     
> -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="/Zc:__cplusplus"         
> -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=C:\mongo-c-driver       
> -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\mongo-cxx-driver  \

I added the "/Zc:__cplusplus" flag as required and it compiled fine!